# MathJax shows extra parameters

Tags: php, moodle, mathjax, mathml

I'm using latex on my Moodle website. I have an issue with MathJax. It shows first parameter of each equation twice (mostly left side of equal operator =). I use following code:

```
<p><span id="docs-internal-guid-618520b2-7fff-707e-1f90-60e30cf92cc1"></span></p>
<p style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><b id="docs-internal-guid-618520b2-7fff-707e-1f90-60e30cf92cc1" style="font-size: 1rem;"><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/qE_PaXNcEbECok0Xfbj89ubXSw3h-Yt3l_HcM3Xai_QlQcLo9suGkEIX_x1bONqRLotS7QFRogRdEytPiqBHcATwjpiUBUaFLzs5GzxTW1zNWjeZe0gFyrvejnNMmJI5MNaEk0Bnmp8" alt="angle" width="500" height="524" class="img-responsive atto_image_button_text-bottom"></b></p>
<p
    style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 1rem;"></span></p>
    <ul style="">
        <li dir="ltr" style="font-weight: bold;">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation" style=""><span style="font-weight: normal;">\(r_S\) = the vector from the center of the earth to the satellite</span></p>
        </li>
        <li dir="ltr" style="">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">\(r_e\) = the vector from the center of the earth to the earth station</p>
        </li>
        <li dir="ltr" style="">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">d = the vector from the earth station to the satellite</p>
        </li>
        <li dir="ltr" style="">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">These vectors are in the same plane and from a triangle</p>
        </li>
        <li dir="ltr" style="">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">\(\gamma\) = angle measured between re and \(r_S\) , i.e. the angle between the earth station and the satellite.</p>
        </li>
        <li dir="ltr" style="">
            <p dir="ltr" role="presentation" style="">\(\psi\) = angle measured from \(r_e\) to d</p>
        </li>
    </ul><span id="docs-internal-guid-da2fbfc2-7fff-6714-037c-8f92356d7f04"><ul style=""><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation" style="">\(\gamma\) can be calculated from the following equation:<br><br><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>L</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>L</mi><mi>S</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>l</mi><mi>S</mi></msub><mo>-</mo><msub><mi>l</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><mo>+</mo><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>L</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>L</mi><mi>S</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\cos (\gamma ) = \cos (L_e)\cos (L_S)\cos (l_S-l_e)+\sin (L_e)\sin(L_S)$$</annotation></semantics></math></p></li></ul><p dir="ltr" style="">Where:</p><ul style=""><ul style=""><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation">\(L_e\) = related to the earth station north Latitude (earth station is north of equator)</p></li><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation">\(L_S\) = Subsatellite point at north Latitude</p></li><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation">\(l_e\) = number in degree in longitude that earth station is west from the Greenwich meridian</p></li><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation" style="">\(l_S\) = west longitude</p></li></ul></ul><span id="docs-internal-guid-c877d197-7fff-28c1-d222-3a1f1e55fc7b"><ul style=""><li dir="ltr" style=""><p dir="ltr" role="presentation" style="">The law of cosines allow us to relate the magnitudes of the vectors joining the center of the earth, the satellite, and the earth station. Therefore, the distance between earth&nbsp; station and satellite:</p></li></ul></span>
    <math
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <semantics>
            <annotation encoding="LaTeX">\(d = r_S \left[1+\left(\frac{r_e}{r_s}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{r_e}{r_s}\right)\cos(\gamma)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\)</annotation>
        </semantics>
        </math><br></span><br>
        <p></p>
        <p style=""><span style=""></span></p>
        <p dir="ltr" style="">Since the local and horizontal plane at the earth station is perpendicular to the \(r_e\). The elevation angle, El, is related to the central angle \(\psi\) by:</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>E</mi><mi>l</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>Ψ</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>90</mn><mo>°</mo><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$El= \Psi- 90^{\circ}$$</annotation></semantics></math>
        <p></p>
        <p style=""><span style=""></span></p>
        <p dir="ltr">From the law of sines:</p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mfrac><msub><mi>r</mi><mi>s</mi></msub><mrow><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>Ψ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfrac><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mi>d</mi><mrow><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfrac><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\frac{r_s}{\sin(\Psi)}=\frac{d}{\sin(\gamma)}$$</annotation></semantics></math>
        <p></p>
        <p style=""><span style=""><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>Ψ</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>90</mn><mo>°</mo><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>Ψ</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>cos</mi><mrow><mi>E</mi><mi>l</mi></mrow><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\cos(\Psi-90^{\circ}) = \sin(\Psi)=\cos{El}$$</annotation></semantics></math></span></p>
        <p
            style=""><span style=""></span></p>
            <p dir="ltr">Combining the above three equations:</p>
            <p dir="ltr"></p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>E</mi><mi>l</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><msub><mi>r</mi><mi>s</mi></msub><mo>×</mo><mfrac><mrow><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mi>d</mi></mfrac><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\cos(El) = r_s \times \frac{\sin(\gamma)}{d} $$</annotation></semantics></math><br><span><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mo>&nbsp;&nbsp;</mo><mo>&nbsp;&nbsp;</mo><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><msup><mfenced close="]" open="["><mrow><mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><msup><mfenced><mfrac><msub><mi>r</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><msub><mi>e</mi><mi>s</mi></msub></mfrac></mfenced><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mn>2</mn><mfenced><mfrac><msub><mi>r</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><msub><mi>r</mi><mi>s</mi></msub></mfrac></mfenced><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfenced><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></msup></mfrac><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\quad \quad~~~=\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\left[1+\left(\frac{r_e}{e_s}\right)^2 -2\left(\frac{r_e}{r_s}\right)\cos(\gamma)\right]^\frac{1}{2}}$$</annotation></semantics></math></span><br><br>
            <span
                id="docs-internal-guid-13cec965-7fff-31c9-595f-a0530817198a">
                <h3><span><span><b>Elevation Angle Calculation of GEO Satellite</b></span></span>
                </h3>
                <p><span><span></span></span>
                </p>
                <p dir="ltr">For Geostationary Satellite:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li dir="ltr">
                        <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">Subsatellite point is on the equator at longitude \(l_S\) and the Latitude \(L_S\) is 0.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li dir="ltr">
                        <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">Geosynchronous radius \(r_S \)= 42,164.17 Km</p>
                    </li>
                    <li dir="ltr">
                        <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">Since \(L_S\) = 0,<br><br><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>c</mi><mi>o</mi><mi>s</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>L</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><mo>×</mo><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>l</mi><mi>s</mi></msub><mo>-</mo><msub><mi>l</mi><mi>e</mi></msub><mo>)</mo><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\cos (\gamma) = cos (L_e) \times \cos (l_s-l_e)$$</annotation></semantics></math></p>
                    </li>
                    <li dir="ltr">
                        <p dir="ltr" role="presentation">Since \(r_S\)=42,164.17 Km and \(r_e\) = 6378.17 Km, hence&nbsp;<br><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mi>d</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>42</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>164</mn><mo>.</mo><mn>17</mn><msup><mfenced close="]" open="["><mrow><mn>1</mn><mo>.</mo><mn>02288235</mn><mo>-</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>.</mo><mn>30253825</mn><mo>×</mo><mi>cos</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>γ</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mfenced><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></msup><annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$d= 42,164.17 \left[1.02288235 - 0.30253825 \times \cos (\gamma)\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$</annotation></semantics></math><br>
                            <math
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                                <semantics>
                                    <mi>cos</mi>
                                    <mo>(</mo>
                                    <mi>E</mi>
                                    <mi>l</mi>
                                    <mo>)</mo>
                                    <mo>=</mo>
                                    <mfrac>
                                        <mrow>
                                            <mi>sin</mi>
                                            <mo>(</mo>
                                            <mi>γ</mi>
                                            <mo>)</mo>
                                        </mrow>
                                        <msup>
                                            <mfenced close="]" open="[">
                                                <mrow>
                                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                                    <mo>.</mo>
                                                    <mn>02288235</mn>
                                                    <mo>-</mo>
                                                    <mn>0</mn>
                                                    <mo>.</mo>
                                                    <mn>32053825</mn>
                                                    <mi>cos</mi>
                                                    <mo>(</mo>
                                                    <mi>γ</mi>
                                                    <mo>)</mo>
                                                </mrow>
                                            </mfenced>
                                            <mfrac>
                                                <mn>1</mn>
                                                <mn>2</mn>
                                            </mfrac>
                                        </msup>
                                    </mfrac>
                                    <annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$\cos(El) = \frac{\sin (\gamma)}{\left[1.02288235 -0.32053825\cos(\gamma)\right]^\frac{1}{2}}$$</annotation>
                                </semantics>
                                </math>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul><b><b><br></b></b>
                </span><br><br>
                <p></p>
```

As it's shown in following image, it shows extra letters and repeated equations in output ! I tried by creating another page, and the result was same.
Any help is appreciated in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your MathML is malformed.  In particular, the `<semantics>` elements are not valid.  The contents of `<semantics>` should be a single MathML node followed by zero or more `<annotation>` or `<annotation-xml>` nodes.  In your case, you have, for example:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <semantics>
    <mi>E</mi>
    <mi>l</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mi>Ψ</mi>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>90</mn>
    <mo>°</mo>
    <annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$El= \Psi- 90^{\circ}$$</annotation>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

which has 7 MathML nodes before the `<annotation>` node.  Because only the first child of a `<semantics>` element is displayed, in this case, only the "E" will be displayed.  You need to wrap the MathML in an `<mrow>` in order for the full expression to be the first child of the `<semantics>` node:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mi>E</mi>
      <mi>l</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mi>Ψ</mi>
      <mo>-</mo>
      <mn>90</mn>
      <mo>°</mo>
    </mrow>
    <annotation encoding="LaTeX">$$El= \Psi- 90^{\circ}$$</annotation>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

You also have some expressions that *start* with an `<annotation>` element as the first child of the `<semantics>` node.  That is also incorrect, as the first child should be a presentation element.  For example:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <semantics>
    <annotation encoding="LaTeX">\(d = r_S \left[1+\left(\frac{r_e}{r_s}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{r_e}{r_s}\right)\cos(\gamma)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\)</annotation>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

This will fail because there is no displayable element as the first child.  (I think it will produce an empty expression.)

I'm not sure why you are getting the full expression displayed after the initial MathML node, but I'm guessing that LaTeX from the `<annotation>` element itself may be what is being typeset.  That shouldn't happen, but you have not given your MathJax configuration or how you are calling it, so I can't tell what might be causing that.  I wasn't able to reproduce that myself.

Also, the MathML does not always correspond to the LaTeX given in the annotation.  most of the annotations have double dollars, meaning displayed math style, but the `<math>` element does not have the `display="block"` attribute, so will be rendered as in-line math.  There are also problems with parentheses that will stretch when you would not expect them to (missing `<mrow>` around the parenthesis groups).  You might find it better to just use the original LaTeX and let MathJax do the conversion to MathML for you.